# Is it posibble to compose XSS string after HTML Entity?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I'm using this NPM package called [xss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss)

My Example Code is this

```js
const xss = require("xss");

const userGeneratedCode =
  '<img src="notValidUrl" onerror=alert(document.cookie)>';

const XssProcessor = new xss.FilterXSS({
  whiteList: {
    a: ["href", "title", "target"]
  }
});

const processedString = XssProcessor.process(userGeneratedCode);
// => &lt;img src="notValidUrl" onerror=alert(document.cookie)&gt;

document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = processedString;
```

The output shows exactly the string

`<img src="notValidUrl" onerror=alert(document.cookie)>`

Is it possible to compose the variable `userGeneratedCode` to get past the `XssProcessor` above, and finally become a dangerous string?

[image]

[image: Edit XSS StackOverflow]

Comment: So you're asking if there are known security vulnerabilities with that library? Or you want us to do a security audit of that library for you? Either way, sounds like it might be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: My concern is that innerHTML is always dangerous no matter what.
If I can compose a certain format of the string and get past through the library and finally become a dangerous string, then I can warn people not using innerHTML at all cost.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's just about whether you want to present user generated content or not. If you do, you have to sanitize it, regardless of whether you use `innerHTML`, serve it straight from the backend, or retrieve it from a 3rd party source.